# MPAndroidChart - dynamic date labels on X axis

Tags: java, android, date, graph, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to change labels on X axis during zooming in MPAndroidChart ? I want to have years as labels at the beginning, than change into months when zooming, then week (labels will become more accurate when zoom).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature **just became available**, please check out the [AxisValueFormatter interface](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface).

It allows to dynamically adjust axis labels before drawing them which means **you can write your own logic** and decide what get's displayed and what not. Always bear in mind that **performance is critical** here as methods of this interface are invoked (potentially) thousands of times when drawing the chart. Especially avoid unnecessary memory allocations or expensive loops.

Comment: Thanks for proper answer with proper reference!

Comment: He should be able to give the proper answer, since he made the library ;)

Comment: Hi @Philipp Jahoda , can you please answer my bounty question regarding xAxis labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325511/mpandroid-chart-not-displaying-any-labels-for-xaxis-what-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment97407907_55325511