# MPAndroid Chart not displaying any labels for xAxis , what is missing?

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm implementing a feature for displaying Incomes/Expenses for properties & also provided Filter for 1 Month , 3 Months , 6 Months & 12 Months .

So, I have to display Months labels according to filter selected for example if 3 Month filter selected then need to display March , Feb & Jan but what currently labels are not displaying on XAxis.

Here is my code , please rectify any issue:

```
private void setChart() {

    ArrayList<BarEntry> incomeEntries = getIncomeEntries();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> expenseEntries = getExpenseEntries();

    BarDataSet set1, set2;

    set1 = new BarDataSet(incomeEntries, "Income");
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(65, 168, 121));
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(55, 70, 73));
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);

    set2 = new BarDataSet(expenseEntries, "Expense");
    set2.setColors(Color.rgb(241, 107, 72));
    set2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(55, 70, 73));
    set2.setValueTextSize(10f);

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    dataSets.add(set2);

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    barChart.setData(data);


    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(10);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);
    barChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);

    Legend l = barChart.getLegend();
    l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
    l.setTextSize(14);
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    l.setDrawInside(false);
    l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);


    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(data.getXMax() + 0.25f);

    ArrayList<String> formatter = getFormattter();

    Log.d(TAG,"Labels Received :"+formatter.size()); // Printing 3

    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(formatter));

    barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(formatter.size(),true);

    Log.d(TAG,"Labels Count :"+xAxis.getLabelCount()); // Printing 3

    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    float maxValue = 0, minValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < incomeEntries.size(); i++) {

        if (maxValue < incomeEntries.get(i).getY()) {
            maxValue = incomeEntries.get(i).getY();
        }

        if (maxValue < expenseEntries.get(i).getY()) {
            maxValue = expenseEntries.get(i).getY();
        }

    }

    maxValue = maxValue + 100;
    Log.e(TAG, "==================== MAX VALUE = " + maxValue);

    leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(maxValue);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(minValue);

    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(maxValue);
    leftAxis.setStartAtZero(true);

    data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());

    //data
    float groupSpace = 0.25f;
    float barSpace = 0.05f; // x2 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.35f; // x2 dataset


    barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(10f);
    barChart.groupBars(10, groupSpace, barSpace);
    barChart.invalidate();

}

private ArrayList<String> getFormattter() {

    Log.e(TAG, "GET FORMATTED VALUE");

    switch (chartType) {

        case AppConstants.CHART_TYPE_1_MONTH:
            monthFormatter();
            return oneMonthLabels;

        case AppConstants.CHART_TYPE_3_MONTH:
            threeMonthFormatter();
            return threeMonthLabels;

        case AppConstants.CHART_TYPE_6_MONTH:
            sixMonthFormatter();
            return sixMonthLabels;

        case AppConstants.CHART_TYPE_12_MONTH:
            yearFormatter();
            return yearLabels;
    }
    return null;
}

private void threeMonthFormatter() {

    Log.e(TAG, "threeMonthFormatter , label list size : " + threeMonthLabels.size());
    if (null != threeMonthLabels) {
        threeMonthLabels.clear();
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTime());
    threeMonthLabels.add(month);

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTime());
    threeMonthLabels.add(month);

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTime());
    threeMonthLabels.add(month);

    for (int i = 0; i < threeMonthLabels.size(); i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Label : " + threeMonthLabels.get(i));
    }
}
```

I have attached screen which is achieved as of now.As you can see as per three month Filter , it's displaying bars as per 3 months but there are no labels even monthFormatter create exactly 3 months labels.

Here is another screenshot to display labels received log from Formatter method.

**Log From Formatter method**
[image]

**Main Screen**
[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider.

Comment: Can you post the following code: new IndexAxisValueFormatter(formatter)

Comment: Hi @Ricardo , formatter is actually ArrayList<String> which has labels received from getFormatter() method, something like this         
ArrayList<String> formatter = getFormattter();
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(formatter));

Is this something you asking for ?

Comment: You have this in you github repo?. anyways will answer this by end of the day.

Comment: @sudesh , sorry not uploaded on github repo . Thanks for your interest & looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @DeepShah can you post the code of the formatter? Thats what gets the values for the Axis

Comment: Also, if this `barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(formatter.size(),true);` returns 0, you wont get labels either

Comment: @Ricardo , I have received 3 labels for 3 months & also able to print xAxis.getLabelCount() with value 3.

Comment: hey @DeepShah. Can you connect to me for some help ?

Comment: Yes @AnshulTyagi , how can I help you ?

Comment: ping me on hangout or chat.stackoverflow.com I have same type of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613135/mpchart-library-is-hiding-x-axis-labels-including-bars)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These two lines are causing the issue :

> ```
> barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(10f);     
> barChart.groupBars(10, groupSpace, barSpace);
> ```

you are setting the minimum value  of x axis to 10, whereas the labels will begin with index 0, So internally IndexOut of bound exception keeps occurring So,

**Change To:**

```
barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(0f);     // Better remove setAxisMinValue(), as it deprecated
barChart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
```

If you still want to have 10 as the initial spacing, override **IAxisValueFormatter** (Not recommended)

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(formatter) {

 @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            int x = (int)value / 10
            if(x > = 0 && x < formatter.size())
               return formatter.get(x);
            else
               return "";
        }
});
```

As you have fixed group space, bar space and width. you will need to heavily customise for multiple dataset.

> However I wouldn't go with your solution for such a dynamic graph,

I have re-written your solution to adapt to changing width. (This are the results)

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/sudeshim3/GroupBarGraph)

[Apk Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wBe_Fz8COp8wPUEhd7Q69rwebZrHrqwX)

[image: 6 month] 
[image: 3 month]

```
BarChart barChart;
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
float defaultBarWidth = -1;
List<String> xAxisValues = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    barChart = findViewById(R.id.barchart);
    setChart(3);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int switchId) {

            switch (switchId) {
                case R.id.one_month:
                    setChart(1);
                    break;
                case R.id.three_month:
                    setChart(3);
                    break;
                case R.id.six_month:
                    setChart(6);
                    break;
                case R.id.tweleve_month:
                    setChart(12);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}


private void setChart(int size) {

    List<BarEntry> incomeEntries = getIncomeEntries(size);
    List<BarEntry> expenseEntries = getExpenseEntries(size);
    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    BarDataSet set1, set2;

    set1 = new BarDataSet(incomeEntries, "Income");
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(65, 168, 121));
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(55, 70, 73));
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);

    set2 = new BarDataSet(expenseEntries, "Expense");
    set2.setColors(Color.rgb(241, 107, 72));
    set2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(55, 70, 73));
    set2.setValueTextSize(10f);

    dataSets.add(set1);
    dataSets.add(set2);

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);

    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(10);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    Legend l = barChart.getLegend();
    l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
    l.setTextSize(14);
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    l.setDrawInside(false);
    l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(getExpenseEntries(size).size());

    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisValues));

    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    setBarWidth(data, size);
    barChart.invalidate();

}

private void setBarWidth(BarData barData, int size) {
    if (dataSets.size() > 1) {
        float barSpace = 0.02f;
        float groupSpace = 0.3f;
        defaultBarWidth = (1 - groupSpace) / dataSets.size() - barSpace;
        if (defaultBarWidth >= 0) {
            barData.setBarWidth(defaultBarWidth);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default Barwdith " + defaultBarWidth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        int groupCount = getExpenseEntries(size).size();
        if (groupCount != -1) {
            barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
            barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + barChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
            barChart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no of bar groups is " + groupCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        barChart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // perform the "explicit" grouping
        barChart.invalidate();
    }
}

private List<BarEntry> getExpenseEntries(int size) {
    ArrayList<BarEntry> expenseEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(1,1710));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(2,2480));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(3,242));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(4,2409));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(5,8100));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(6,1200));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(7,6570));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(8,5455));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(9,15000));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(10,11340));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(11,9100));
    expenseEntries.add(new BarEntry(12,6300));
    return expenseEntries.subList(0, size);
}

private List<BarEntry> getIncomeEntries(int size) {
    ArrayList<BarEntry> incomeEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, 11300));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, 1390));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, 1190));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, 7200));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(5, 4790));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(6, 4500));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(7, 8000));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(8, 7034));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(9, 4307));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(10, 8762));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(11, 4355));
    incomeEntries.add(new BarEntry(12, 6000));
    return incomeEntries.subList(0, size);
}
```

Note that the `setBarWidth()` function is the most important and plays the role of adjusting the width and size of graph bar.

Comment: @Deepshah, did the solution help.? or are you still facing some issue.

Comment: @sudesh Hi. I'm also facing a  [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613135/mpchart-library-is-hiding-x-axis-labels-including-bars), it would be great if you can help me in it.

Comment: Superb Solutions bro. Helped me a lot

Comment: @sudesh hey , i am working on something similar but facing problem with the value as it is predefined ,which is (0,20,40,..) and i want to display my string arraylist values on x-axis but while returning values it takes index value as 20 and there is nothing in my arraylist at 20 index ..here is what i am trying to do...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791105/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-horizontal-bar-for-representing-data?noredirect=1#comment111041251_62791105 ..please help

Comment: @payal_suthar, I couldn't find the question in the above-mentioned link

Comment: @sudesh ,sorry i deleted that one as it was violating the guidelines and posted a new one ..Here is the question ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829006/how-to-display-available-and-unavailable-slots-in-a-horizontal-bar-graph-in-andr ... please help me through this

Comment: @payal_suthar, the correct way of implementing this is using HorizontalBarGraph and stacked bar entry. In your case setting width is not recommended. I Have posted the answer to your StackOverflow question. you can try out the project linked in your answers comment section.

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution, if someone is looking for decreasing the bar width then just increase the groupSpace.. dont change the formula for  barwidth or it will mess with labels again.

Answer (score 2):

**Replace below line**

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter(formatter));
```

**instead of**

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(formatter));
```

**and check.**

Comment: Thanks. pointed me in the right direction. ir's now ValueFormatter()